# PRAW/PYTHON, how to fix 400 HTTP Response in .comments function?

Tags: python, api, reddit, praw

I'm trying to scrape reddit comments, and I'm having difficulty sending requests to reddit. It seems that somewhere along my short script some bad syntax has occurred. Can anyone spot it?

I've tried with and without the redirect_uri. Under my Reddit app page it says my app is authorized. I also tried changing the user_agent name to something else besides my username but that still didn't work. I'm unsure what other information to provide.

```
import praw #Python Reddit API Wrapper

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='ID', \ #the personal number
                     client_secret='SECRET', \ #the secret number
                     user_agent='Username', \ #Identical to username
                     username='Username', \ #Identical to user_agent
                     password='PW', \ 
                     redirect_uri='http://localhost:8080')

#confirm connection:
print(reddit.user.me()) # this works and returns my Username

submission = reddit.submission("https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/ch6oz0/amasian/")
submission.comments #this fails and returns:

  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 130, in _request_with_retries
    raise self.STATUS_EXCEPTIONS[response.status_code](response)

BadRequest: received 400 HTTP response
```

Comment: I've changed the redirect_uri to exclude ':8080', then I managed to obtain a code and state for authorization. Next, I was able to use that code to retrieve the refresh token. I've upgraded the requests package, and so far none of these has made a difference.

Comment: Never really fixed this problem. I switched to using stream.comments from praw.Reddit(...).subreddit.stream.comments to then insert into postgresql database in real time. This sufficed for my project for now, so I won't update this thread again/for awhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
help(reddit.submission)
Help on method submission in module praw.reddit:

submission(id=None, url=None) method of praw.reddit.Reddit instance
    Return a lazy instance of :class:`~.Submission`.

    :param id: A reddit base36 submission ID, e.g., ``2gmzqe``.
    :param url: A URL supported by
        :meth:`~praw.models.Submission.id_from_url`.`.

    Either ``id`` or ``url`` can be provided, but not both.
```

submission() thinks I was entering an ID because I didn't specify url=''.

Can't mourn too hard, case closed, folks.

Comment: Here's the [web version](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/reddit_instance.html#praw.Reddit.submission) of the documentation, which says the same thing.